# Run multiple instances of gnome-system-monitor

Tags: system-monitor

Is there any way to run multiple instances of gnome-system-monitor (System Monitor)? I often find myself needing to use it in multiple sessions (physical and remote) on the same machine, and I'd rather not have to run `killall gnome-system-monitor` every time.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do it. Open two terminal windows or terminal tabs then type there as `gnome-system-monitor` in two windows/tabs & remember change one user to root in your terminal and keep the user in other terminal as usual. so that you can have two system monitors opened.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. Running the second instance, just brings the first instance to the top.

Comment: I have updated @SimplySimon . please try now.

Comment: You are welcome my friend.